Is JBoss 8 compatible with java 8?
I am trying to migrate an ear application from JBoss 7.1 eap to jboss 8, is it compatible with java 8?
I get the following error
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jboss/modules/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0


The minimum Java SE version for Jakarta EE 10 is Java SE 11. So it can't be compatible
